# how to use WCF Service in Xamarin.Forms Portable class library

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am trying to call method created correctly using WCF, I start debugging the project for WCF and the result as the following:
[image]

on my **xamarin.forms** code i used `HttpClient` Library as the following:

```
 private async Task DownloadInfo()
        {
            var Uri = "http://localhost:10300/RestServiceImpl.svc/json";
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var json= await  httpClient.GetStringAsync(Uri);
        }
```

when I am trying to get `json` result from **Xamarin.Forms** I get the following: 
[image]

what I should do?

Comment: you need to use the IP or FQDN of your server, not "localhost".

Comment: that is right Jason .thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are inspecting the task there, this doesnt give that much information. You can try this little more structured approach.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:10300");
            var request = "/RestServiceImpl.svc/json";

            var result = await httpClient.GetAsync(request);

            if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                throw new HttpRequestException($"{result.StatusCode} \n {result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result} \n\n {httpClient.BaseAddress}{request}");

            var json = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Debug.WriteLine(json);
}
```