# How to make https webAPI call?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make https webAPI call, specifically - Google Directions API. Putting the uri directly inside browser gives me the result that I want, so I'm 100% sure my uri is correct.

Now, how do I call the webapi inside my PCL? Using modernhttp and HttpClient now, but am open to whatever options there are out there.

```
private async Task<string> GetJsonObjFromUrl(string urlRoutes)
{
    HttpClient c = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());

    var resp = await c.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri(urlRoutes)));

    if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var json = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return json;
    }

    return null;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Just putting this here because this was driving me crazy whole night. Ends up the caller way, way above forgot to put await. The execution continues straight after and never returns to get the result. That's why I never got any results... :\

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` Why do you think you're doing something wrong? Are you getting a compile-time error? An exception? A deadlock? An unexpected result?

Comment: The code just don't go hit anywhere below client.SendAsync / GetStringAsync

Comment: @Farid try this one https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/transport-layer-security/

Comment: check the following links : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41680217/how-to-use-wcf-service-in-xamarin-forms-portable-class-library/41808780#41808780

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The code just don't go hit anywhere below client.SendAsync / GetStringAsync

I suspect that further up your call stack, your code is calling `Result` / `Wait` / `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on a task. If called from a UI thread, this will [deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), as I explain on my blog.

The deadlock is caused by the `async` method attempting to resume on the UI context, but the UI thread is blocked waiting for the task to complete. Since the `async` method must complete in order to complete its task, there's a deadlock.

The proper fix is to replace that `Result` / `Wait` with `await`.

Answer (score 0):

In your PCL use:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(Url);
```

In case of using HTTPS.
In Android, your main activity:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=(sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
}
```

In iOS, in your AppDelegate:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with https. Is this supposed to work with https?

Comment: if the certificate is untrusted, you should use: ServerCertificateValidationCallback, and accept it yourself to establish TLS session

Comment: You mean something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251689/make-https-call-using-httpclient? The WebRequestHandler class isn't in XF. How do I establish TLS?

Comment: I mean this only: ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

Comment: Okay, I'm totally out of my depth here. Can you give a full example please? I'm not a web dev, just doing this as self learning. How / where do I subscribe the ServerCertificateValidationCallback?

Comment: Okay, I'll complete my example in the answer.